# ArcGIS Android SDK MapView.removeLayer method not working

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-android

I'm currently exploring ArcGIS's Android SDK.

However, I've found that when adding a `ShapefileFeatureTable` to a `FeatureLayer`:

```
    FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileFeatureTable);
    featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol(
            getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright),
            SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE.SOLID)));
    mapView.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

and then trying to remove it:

```
    mapView.removeLayer(featureLayer);
```

it doesn't work! **(the layer is still visible)**

I've tried to change the following:

```
    mapView.addLayer(featureLayer,0);
    mapView.removeLayer(0);
```

and this doesn't work either.

**EXPLANATORY NOTE:** I'm trying to add and remove the feature layer because I want to show a `GraphicsLayer` on the map, but if I don't load a `FeatureLayer` first, the `MapView` stays completely black.  I tried to set the `SpatialReference` and the background grid, but the only thing that worked was adding a bogus `FeatureLayer` first.  I eventually "fixed it" by calling:

```
mapView.addLayer(featureLayer);
featureLayer.setVisible(false);
```

But I still think it's suboptimal solution.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the problem occurred because the layer wasn't added yet when I tried to remove it (the layer addition is an asynchronous process), so you need to add a listener:

```
    mapView.addLayer( featureLayer );
    mapView.setOnStatusChangedListener( new OnStatusChangedListener() {
        // adding and removing immediately doesn't work
        // you need to wait until the featureLayer is fully added/loaded to be able to remove it
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged( Object o, STATUS status ) {
            if ( o == featureLayer ) {
                if ( status == STATUS.LAYER_LOADED ) {
                    mapView.removeLayer( featureLayer );
                    mapView.setOnStatusChangedListener( null );
                }
            }
        }
    } );
```

I added the `setOnStatusChangedListener` back to `null` to not have the callback be run every time the map status changes.